# How to use oAuth with twitter4j?

Tags: java, twitter, oauth, twitter4j

I'm experimenting for the first time with a twitter API called 'Twitter4J', I've looked at tutorials but by the looks of it all of them still use the basic authentication that twitter got rid of and replaced with oAuth.

I work with java and is writing the app as a java application(not web application). Is there anybody that might have some experience with twitter4J and oAuth?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are so many examples in the internet.
These helped me in particular:
http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html and 
http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html

Comment: shouldn't link to tutorials, just rewrite the contents here.